# SailsJS skipper-s3 docs suggests S3 bucket should be in US standard - but no such region in S3 UI

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sails.js, sails-skipper

Referring to the SailsJS Skipper-S3 doc here: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/file-uploads/uploading-to-s-3 the box says:

> Please note that your Amazon S3 bucket must be created in the 'US Standard' region. If you fail to do so, you will get a 'TypeError('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.').

However, looks like Amazon S3's new bucket UI does not have "US Standard" as any of the listed regions.

So where should I be creating the S3 bucket now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[S3 Regions](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#regions)

> Q. Wasn’t there a **US Standard region**?
>
> We renamed the US Standard Region to **US East (Northern Virginia)**
>   Region to be consistent with AWS regional naming conventions. There is
>   no change to the endpoint and you do not need to make any changes to
>   your application.

Comment: Yup - use to be global, then US Standard became US-EAST-1